# SVG not scrollable in webkit browsers when inserted using <object>

Tags: html, svg, webkit, scrollable

I try to add a svg drawing to a html page. The different elements in the SVG have mouseover properties, that only work if the SVG is inserted inside an `<object>` tag. The mouseover does not work when it is inserted using the `<img>` tag.

My problem is that, the svg drawing is rather big (on purpose) and take 100% of the page width:

```
<object data='mydrawing.svg' width="100%" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

By doing so, the height of the svg is bigger than the height of the page. The problem is that webkit browsers (I tried Chrome and Safari) seems to "cut" the SVG file at the page limit. In other, when I scroll down, I directly reach the footer of the page, not the bottom of my drawing.

This is how it look:

And this is how it should look:

I do not have the issue if I use firefox or if the svg is inserted in an `<img>` tag (but in that case, as I mentioned above, the mouseover does not work anymore).

Any idea how to fix my problem?

Comment: I believe <object> is creating a boundary around the element inside it, so its size is the svg's size why not just put the <svg> tag directly inside your HTML?

Comment: @nrathaus in that case, it does not load the file anymore...

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, HTML5 allows you to put <svg> right inside a <body> element

Comment: @nrathaus sorry, what I mean, is that I can not copy the whole svg directly in the html because the it is a template, used in different pages across the website, and loading a different svg on every page. So the svg should be loaded dynamically not hard coded into the html directly. I hope it makes sense...

Comment: Did you try <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" /> ?

Comment: Did you try <iframe src="image.svg">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe> ?

Comment: Last option <img src="image.svg" /> ?

Comment: @nrathaus <embed> gives the exact same result... <img> works, but the mouseover properties are not working anymore. <iframe> works but messes up some other part of my page (this: http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/ does not work anymore)...

Comment: @nrathaus no problem, thanks anymway. I'll keep digging

Comment: @nrathaus I just found out it works if I scroll **outside** the svg file. Since the width was set to 100% I could not see it. If it is set to 80% and I scroll next to the image, it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can load an SVG file as XML, using **XMLHttpRequest** into you your web page, and it can be arranged to fill the screen. Also, all events in the svg file are available.

Try the following example with your svg file.(tested OK for IE/FF/CH/OP)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body style='overflow:hidden'>
<div id="svgDiv" style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px'></div>
<script>
//----onload---
function loadSVGasXML()
{
    var SVGFile="yourSVGFile.svg"

    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
    function handler()
    {
        if(loadXML.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (loadXML.status == 200) //---loaded ok---
            {
                var xmlString=loadXML.responseText
                svgDiv.innerHTML=xmlString
                sizeFull()
            }
        }
    }
    if (loadXML != null)
    {
        loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
        loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
        loadXML.send();
    }
}
//--onload, onresize----
function sizeFull()
{
    var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
    var svgW=window.innerWidth
    var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height

    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
    mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
    mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
window.onresize=sizeFull
document.addEventListener("onload",loadSVGasXML(),false)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```